# Add a custom 'order by date' button on WP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im looking for a way to create an 'order by date' custom button in a WP loop, the website is running under _S theme (running from scratch, indeed).

In the section below, I made a filtering system like [this one](https://codepen.io/Chaaampy/pen/gWOrvp), but I need to build a date filtering system too.

In this loop, the article are displayed by default (by date DESC I guess ?).

I know how to get the date with the WP functions, but after that, Im struggling a bit.

Any idea please ?

Thx :)

```
<div class="wrap-tags container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="filters">
                <li>Filtres</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="date">Date</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="trigger">Tags</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="tags">
                <li><button class="link" data-rel="all" href="javascript:void(0)">ALL</button></li>
                <li><button class="link" data-rel="un" href="javascript:void(0)">Un</button></li>
                <li><button class="link" data-rel="deux" href="javascript:void(0)">Deux</button></li>
                <li><button class="link" data-rel="trois" href="javascript:void(0)">Trois</button></li>
                <li><button class="link" data-rel="quatre" href="javascript:void(0)">Quatre</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="container blog-article-actu">
            <div class="row">

    <?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=-1');

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
    $catObj = get_the_category();
    $get_the_tags = get_the_tags();

        ?>

        <article class="blog-article-actu-article all <?php foreach ($get_the_tags as $leTab){ echo $leTab->name . " "; } ?>" style="background:url('<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?><?php echo $url ?>');">
            <div class="blog-article-actu-article-top">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="details-blog-article-actu">
                    <div class="blog-article-actu-date">
                        <span class="day"><?php the_time( 'd' ) ?></span>
                        <span class="month"><?php the_time( 'F' ) ?></span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </article>

    <?php  // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>

            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still interested, in my case, I 'cheated' by reversing the articles with jQuery (while the articles are displayed by date by default).